# Push notifications only in the moment?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, service-worker

I'm using service workers and push notifications with nodejs web-push, to send messages akin to

> *x* user is doing *y*

If the browser is open when this message arrives, it's fine, but if the browser is offline, one is flooded with messages of things that are no longer relevant. Is there anyway to automatically dismiss this messages if they're too old, or set an expiration so it doesn't show up hours later?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, these are the options:

```
const options = {
  gcmAPIKey: '< GCM API Key >',
  vapidDetails: {
    subject: '< \'mailto\' Address or URL >',
    publicKey: '< URL Safe Base64 Encoded Public Key >',
    privateKey: '< URL Safe Base64 Encoded Private Key >'
  },
  TTL: <Number>,
  headers: {
    '< header name >': '< header value >'
  }
}
```

You can set a low TTL so that it doesn't remain in the system for too long. The TTL by default is 4 weeks.

> TTL is a value in seconds that describes how long a push message is
>   retained by the push service (by default, four weeks).

Comment: I did read TTL from the documentation, but I didn't know exactly what it was, thank you for the clarification!